# Why the instance and static inner class initializations are different?

Tags: java, class, static, stack, inner-classes

As we know to create the object of instance inner class we have to follow this syntax

```
<OuterClassName>.<InnerClassName> innerObj = outerObj.new <InnerClassName>(arguments);
```

And for static class the syntax is like this

```
<OuterClassName>.<InnerClassName> innerObj = new <OuterClassName>.<InnerClassName>(arguments);
```

But i am not able to understand the difference between `outerObj.new <InnerClassName>(arguments);` and `new <OuterClassName>.<InnerClassName>(arguments);` in order to create an object.

Answer (score 4):

When the inner class in not static, you need the outer class' reference to refer to it .. hence outerObj.new InnerClass(). And you don't need outer class instance (object) for referring to static inner classes.

Comment: Yes, and the OuterClassName in `new <OuterClassName>.<InnerClassName>` is only a matter of namespace resolution.

Comment: @Sudanshu but why the position of keyword "new" is changing ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you have a static class, you cannot instanciate it in the first place, so you don't have such outerObj, through which you could create the desired inner class instance.